# HTML: Single quote is showing with space on this website but only in certain browsers (i.e. in Chrome on a desktop but not in Safari on iOS)

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, zen-cart

In Chrome and on a desktop, take a look at https://www.alilang.com/gv_faq.html.  You'll see that all single quotes appear as single quote PLUS A SPACE.  For example, in the first sentence, "you'll" appears as "you' ll"

In Chrome's Inspect mode, I just found out that if I erase the single quote and then retype the single quote, it then removes the space and the single quote now appears correct.

Upon closer inspection, the original single quote is at a slight angle, while the normal single quote is straight up and down.
I believe some of this content was coded in China, or perhaps copied and pasted in from Word.

Does anyone know why there is this single quote with a slant and then the single quote that is straight up and down (i.e. the one that shares the key with the double quote)?

Is it due to regional keyboard settings- perhaps a virtual key due to Chinese input type?  Is it due to copying and pasting the content from Word?

Considering I spotted the difference when I was typing this question, at this point, I'm just trying to understand the cause for further knowledge.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your font you're using

Answer (score 2):

There are three types of apostrophes: straight single apostrophes, opening single apostrophes, and closing single apostrophes. The latter two are slightly curved/angled, depending on what font is rendering them. The apostrophes on that site are closing single apostrophes.

Switching between the three types of apostrophes usually doesn't cause a problem, but in this case, the font they are using, Hiragino Sans GB, places a space before the closing single apostrophe.

You can see yourself by removing that font from the font-family list on the page.